# Shared memory model and distributed memory model

Tags: c++, memory, parallel-processing, shared-memory

Say your cpu has the current hardware architecture below in logic gates:
[image]

Say we have a shared memory model and distributed model:
[image]

[image]

Is it correct to say if we wanted to implement a shared memory model and parallel process threads, we would require some utility like OpenMP. Would the shared memory be L3 cache or RAM main memory? And to implement a distributed memory model, we would require some utility such as MPI and multiple computing systems(computers)?

Comment: is your question about distributed L1/2 caches?

Comment: Im trying to understand how these memory models translate into real hardware logic components. Is the memory on the shared memory model the main memory or shared L3 cache?

Comment: No, the main memory typically stays the main memory. In fact, parallel execution does nothing correlated with caching, if the caching is beneficiable is the result of the optimizing compiler, not of the parallel library.
Distributed memory models assume different address spaces and all, for which you would either use MPI (preferably) or raw processes in combination with pipes.

Comment: So what is shared memory? It must be the RAM, when machine is loaded and run the OS creates a process with virtual memory, a main thread executes and secondary threads execute from this main thread, they have access to the processes shared resources....

Comment: shared memory is about having a hunk of memory that 'many' processes can access either in read, write or both. Sharing memory with parallel execution does not mean "distributed". That said, you can consider that distributed systems are just parts of a larger system including all cores and processes, then the shared memory need to be "distributed" but this still means that is can be accessed by any process in the (large) system. Caching is not envolved in this model, even if it can have impacts (need to keep consistency of the whole shared zone, maybe invalidating cache, sometimes..)

Comment: this is really a wide subject, you may have a look to https://www.amazon.fr/Distributed-Systems-Principles-Andrew-Tanenbaum/dp/0131217860 if you did not already did.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is exactly that, until you start working on NUMA.

So let's start from the beginning. If you have cores that share the same memory space, then you can use threads and libraries/tools like OpenMP or TBB (if you are in C++, use TBB, not OpenMP). You can also use MPI here.

If you have interconnects, then the only option is to use a library like MPI.

Now, there is the case in-between, the Non-Uniform Memory Architectures. That happens if you have for instance two sockets, meaning two memory spaces that are connected to one socket each and still accessible from the other socket, and if you have one program with several threads running on a multi-sockets node, you can have memory allocated on one socket that is accessed by a core on another socket, and this is slow.

So what people can do in these cases is:

- one process per socket (and not per node, because of NUMA)
- pinned threads to core, memory to sockets
- on a socket, use TBB
- outside one socket, use MPI.

I'm not saying "often" because lots of scientific code are still MPI only and may be struggling to introduce threading, it's a completely different approach due to memory sharing.

Comment: Why TBB over OpenMP?

Comment: TBB is better for C++, OpenMP has a bad task model (even the guys from the committee say so), and you can do things from a  higher level with TBB, or another C++ library for that matter.